# Streaming audio to DialogFlow for real-time intent recognition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-speech-api, pepper

I'm trying to stream audio from a (Pepper robot) microphone to DialogFlow. I have working code for sending a block of audio. When I send the request, the response contains the message `None Exception iterating requests!`. I've seen this error previously when I was reading from an audio file. However, I fail to see what's wrong with the data I'm passing now.

`processRemote` is called whenever the microphone records something. When writing the `sound_data[0].tostring()` to a StringIO and later retrieving it in chunks of 4096 bytes, the solution works.

`self.processing_queue` is supposed to hold a few chunks of audio that should be processed before working on new audio.

The error occurs in the response for `self.session_client.streaming_detect_intent(requests)`.

I'm thankful for any idea.

```
    def processRemote(self, nbOfChannels, nbOfSamplesByChannel, timeStamp, inputBuffer):
        """audio stream callback method with simple silence detection"""
        sound_data_interlaced = np.fromstring(str(inputBuffer), dtype=np.int16)
        sound_data = np.reshape(sound_data_interlaced,
                                (nbOfChannels, nbOfSamplesByChannel), 'F')
        peak_value = np.max(sound_data)
        chunk = sound_data[0].tostring()
        self.processing_queue.append(chunk)
        if self.is_active:
            # detect sound
            if peak_value > 6000:
                print("Peak:", peak_value)
                if not self.recordingInProgress:
                    self.startRecording()

            # if recording is in progress we send directly to google
            try:
                if self.recordingInProgress:
                    print("preparing request proc remote")
                    requests = [dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(input_audio=chunk)]
                    print("should send now")
                    responses = self.session_client.streaming_detect_intent(requests)
                    for response in responses:
                        print("checking response")
                        if len(response.fulfillment_text) != 0:
                            print("response not empty")
                            self.stopRecording(response)  # stop if we already know the intent
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

    def startRecording(self):
        """init a in memory file object and save the last raw sound buffer to it."""
        # session path setup
        self.session_path = self.session_client.session_path(DIALOG_FLOW_GCP_PROJECT_ID, self.uuid)
        self.recordingInProgress = True
        requests = list()

        # set up streaming
        print("start streaming")
        q_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(audio_config=self.audio_config)
        req = dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(
                        session=self.session_path, query_input=q_input)
        requests.append(req)

        # process pre-recorded audio
        print("work on stored audio")
        for chunk in self.processing_queue:
            print("appending chunk")
            try:
                requests.append(dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(input_audio=chunk))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        print("getting response")
        responses = self.session_client.streaming_detect_intent(requests)
        print("got response")
        print(responses)

        # iterate though responses from pre-recorded audio
        try:
            for response in responses:
                print("checking response")
                if len(response.fulfillment_text) != 0:
                    print("response not empty")
                    self.stopRecording(response)  # stop if we already know the intent
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        # otherwise continue listening
        print("start recording (live)")

    def stopRecording(self, query_result):
        """saves the recording to memory"""
        # stop recording
        self.recordingInProgress = False
        self.disable_google_speech(force=True)
        print("stopped recording")

        # process response
        action = query_result.action
        text = query_result.fulfillment_text.encode("utf-8")
        if (action is not None) or (text is not None):
            if len(text) != 0:
                self.speech.say(text)
            if len(action) != 0:
                parameters = query_result.parameters
                self.execute_action(action, parameters)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/blob/master/dialogflow_v2/gapic/sessions_client.py#L358) the `session_client.streaming_detect_intent` function expects an iterable as its argument. But you are currently giving it a list of requests.

**Won't work:**

```py
requests = [dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(input_audio=chunk)]
responses = self.session_client.streaming_detect_intent(requests) 
#None Exception iterating requests!
```

**Alternatives:**

```py
# wrap the list in an iterator
requests = [dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(input_audio=chunk)]
responses = self.session_client.streaming_detect_intent(iter(requests))

# Note: The example in the source code calls the function like this
# but this gave me the same error
requests = [dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(input_audio=chunk)]
for response in self.session_client.streaming_detect_intent(requests):
    # process response
```

#### Using generator structure

While this fixed the error, the intent detection still didn't work. I believe a better program structure is to use a generator, as suggested in the docs. Something like (pseudo-code):

```py
def dialogflow_mic_stream_generator():
    # open stream
    audio_stream = ...

    # send configuration request
    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(audio_config=audio_config)
    yield dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(session=session_path,
            query_input=query_input)

    # output audio data from stream
    while audio_stream_is_active:
        chunk = audio_stream.read(chunk_size)
        yield dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(input_audio=chunk)

requests = dialogflow_mic_stream_generator()
responses = session_client.streaming_detect_intent(requests)

for response in responses:
    # process response
```